# How to make a network interface stop working without shutting it down?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, shutdown, interface

I will try to explain my problem:

I have a VM in VirtualBox working as a router with 2 others VM attached to enp0s8 and enp0s9. These 2 VM work as hosts.

I am running a NETCONF server in the router and I connect it to a SDN Controller (ONOS) in MY host machine.

In the NETCONF server I've loaded YANG modules that implement an alarms system, therefore when an interface on the router stops working it should be notified to the SDN Controller, here's the problem:

I'm trying to test it and if in the router I take down one of these interfaces with "$ifconfig enp0s8 down", the NETCONF server will be shutdowned, therefore no alarm is generated to the SDN Controller.

**Therefore I was looking for a way to make one of these interfaces stop working (traffic not going through it) but keeping its state up, in order to generate the alarm without the NETCONF server shutdowning itself.**

Any clue on how to do this?

Comment: I'm refloating this.